# Android TV Global Search

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-tv

Is it possible to replicate what Global Search does on Android TV in your own application?

Basically, what I want is to search for a movie (John Wick) it query's all the apps which have content providers implemented and pull the results back to the sample app (This is what Global Search on Android TV does)

Any links, suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: Hey, have you figured this out? I would like to achieve the same :)

Comment: Nope, haven't made progress here

Comment: Did you got any way to do it?, I'm also looking for the same

Comment: Nope, haven't made progress here